# Cannot run application in Eclipse CDT on Windows 7

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows-7, mingw

When I'm trying to run "Hello World" in Eclipse CDT Indigo on Windows 7 using MinGW I have the following problems:

**While debugging:**
I can pass through all lines of the code, but finally I get the message:

> warning: FTH: (6052):  Fault tolerant heap shim applied to current process. This is usually due to previous crashes.
>   Quit (expect signal SIGINT when the program is resumed)

**While normally running:**
Nothing happens, I get only `<terminated>` in the status bar.

Unfortunately I can't modify register on the computer I am running the program, so I can't globally disable the FTH service.

Has anyone met the same problem?

Comment: I had to resolve the problem with using cygwin. MinGW seems not to be happy to coperate with windows 7 :)